# ¿Cómo ocultar un ´Webview´ y mostrar un layout en xamarin IOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

¿Cómo puedo cambiar de un `layout` a otro en **Xamarin**?
Poder cambiar de paginas. Por ejemplo que le de a un botón y este me lleve a otra vista.

Answer (score 0):

Con:

```
Navigation.PushAsync()
```

Si estas usando un NavigationPage y quieres que la otra pantalla tenga el botón de [< Back] / [< Atras].

o con

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync()
```

Si no tienes NavigationPage o si quieres que la pantalla se muestre de forma modal.